# Not sorting alphabetically after submit the form

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, sorting, submit

I have sorted dropdown menu with cities. It's sorted correctly, but after clicking the submit button, their order isn't alphabetical.
Query:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select ID, post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id", ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: use `ORDER BY` clause in Query, and add more code to your question, it would help us to understand your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use bellow code hope it will help you-

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select ID, post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id ORDER BY post_title ASC", ARRAY_A );
```

for more https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb